# Is flask required for a discord bot?

Tags: python, flask, discord

I am writing a discord bot, but flask is doing some annoying stuff such as forcing me to use `kill -9` on it. Is it ok to write a discord bot without flask? Some tutorials I've read use flask, but I am confused as to if it is required or not.

Comment: You can write a Discord bot without _Python_. No, Flask is not required. However, it is likely your problems are not due to Flask, and seeing why exactly you have issues might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don't need flask for a discord bot. Please look into creating a discord bot using python [here](https://realpython.com/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-python/).